# Navigating back to main menu View in SwiftUI with Alert Button

Tags: swiftui, navigationview, swiftui-navigationlink

I have an app with two defined views. I use NavigationView to move between them. I wanted the alert button to switch users back to Main Menu View and I have even found an answer, but after I used it, it produced the screen like this:
[image: A 2 backs bug]

How can I let my app navigate back to the main view from the secondary view in a better way?

The code for the second view (first is just a NavigationLink pointing to the second):

```
import SwiftUI

struct GameView: View {
    
    
    @State private var questionCounter = 1
    
    @State var userAnswer = ""
    
    @State private var alertTitle = ""
    
    @State private var gameOver = false
    @State private var menuNavigation = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack{
                NavigationLink(destination:ContentView(), isActive: $menuNavigation){
                    Text("")
                }
            VStack{
                
                Text("Give the answer")
                TextField("Give it", text: $userAnswer)
                
                Button("Submit", action: answerQuestion)
            }
            .alert(isPresented: $gameOver) {
                Alert(title: Text(alertTitle),
                      dismissButton: Alert.Button.default(
                        Text("Back to menu"), action: {
                            menuNavigation.toggle()
                        }
                      )
                )
                }
            }
            }
            
            }
    
    func answerQuestion() {
        
        questionCounter += 1
        
        if questionCounter == 2 {
            gameOver.toggle()
            alertTitle = "Game Over"
        
        }
        
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-make-a-view-dismiss-itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you are expecting, you actually need to add the `NavigationView` inside `ContentView`, if that's your main view. Because you navigate from `ContentView` to `GameView`, and what you are asking here is how to navigate back.

Applying the concept above, you can just dismiss `GameView` to go back to the in view.

Here is a sample code to achieve that:

Example of main view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                GameView()
                
                    // This is how you hide the "<Back" button, so the user
                    // can navigate back only when tapping the alert
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
            } label: {
                Text("Go to game view")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example of game view:

```
struct GameView: View {
    
    // This variable will dismiss the view
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @State private var questionCounter = 1
    @State var userAnswer = ""
    @State private var alertTitle = ""
    @State private var gameOver = false
    
    // No need to use this variable
    // @State private var menuNavigation = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        // No need to have a NavigationView
        // NavigationView {
        
            // ZStack has no function apparently...
            // ZStack{
        
                // No need to have a NavigationLink
                // NavigationLink(destination:ContentView(), isActive: $menuNavigation){
                //    Text("")
                //}
            VStack {
                
                Text("Give the answer")
                TextField("Give it", text: $userAnswer)
                
                Button("Submit", action: answerQuestion)
            }
            .alert(isPresented: $gameOver) {
                Alert(title: Text(alertTitle),
                      dismissButton: Alert.Button.default(
                        Text("Back to menu"), action: {
                            
                            // This is how you go back to ContentView
                            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        }
                      )
                )
        }
    }
    
    
    func answerQuestion() {
        
        questionCounter += 1
        
        if questionCounter == 2 {
            gameOver.toggle()
            alertTitle = "Game Over"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to make the suggested approach even easier (without using the whole presentationMode syntax):

```
struct GameView: View {
   
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @State private var questionCounter = 1
    @State var userAnswer = ""
    @State private var alertTitle = ""
    @State private var gameOver = false
   
    
    var body: some View {
    
            VStack {
                
                Text("Give the answer")
                TextField("Give it", text: $userAnswer)
                
                Button("Submit", action: answerQuestion)
            }
            .alert(isPresented: $gameOver) {
                Alert(title: Text(alertTitle),
                      dismissButton: Alert.Button.default(
                        Text("Back to menu"), action: {
                            
                            dismiss()
                        }
                      )
                )
        }
    }
    
    
    func answerQuestion() {
        
        questionCounter += 1
        
        if questionCounter == 2 {
            gameOver.toggle()
            alertTitle = "Game Over"
        }
    }
}
```